# Is it possible to construct a vector space on convolution

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, distribution-theory, pseudo-differential-operators

Let $S$ be a set of functions on $R$ such that for any two functions $f$ and $g$ in $S$, the convolution:
$$
(f{\ast}g)(x)={\int}f(y)\ g(x-y)\ dy
$$
exists.  Since the Dirac delta is technically not a function, exclude it from any consideration.  Is it possible to define an identity element for convolution that is also a member of $S$?  And, is it possible to define a unique inverse element for each member of $S$ such that the convolution produces the identity element?  If not can the set of functions, $S$, be restricted to some special subset such that an identity element and unique inverse elements are possible under convolution?

Comment: What is the domain of integration? Over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The Dirac delta function is essentially defined to be the identity. If you think about it, you are trying to find a function that pulls out a single point from your domain of integration but ignores all others. So, we can find a sequence of functions $f_n$ in your set so that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n * g = g$ but $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n$ does not exist.

Comment: Part 1:  So if I take $\varphi_\varepsilon(x)=\left(1/\varepsilon\sqrt{\pi}\right){\exp}(x^2/{\varepsilon^2})$ for $\varepsilon>0$ then, $\varphi_\varepsilon\ {\in}\ S$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$ and $f{\ast}\varphi_\varepsilon\ {\approx}\ f$ as $\varepsilon{\rightarrow}0$ but never reaches zero.  I'm alright with that because each $\varphi_\varepsilon$ is a member of $S$ and I could choose how close $f{\ast}\varphi_\varepsilon$ needs to be to $f$.  I could define $\varphi_\varepsilon$ an approximate identity element for $S$.  --Continues to part 2 (the next comment)

Comment: Part 2:  As far as I could tell from the internet research I have done in the past 24 hours, I have learned that some distributions have an inverse element for convolution the set of invertible distributions forms an abelian group under the convolution.  Can anyone tell me which distributions are invertible under convolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer: If functions in $S$ are integrable and if $S$ contains a function like $e^{-x^{2}}$ of $e^{-|x|}$ or $\frac 1 {1+x^{2}}$ or any function which Fourier transform never vanishes then you cannot have an identity element in $S$. This is because If $g$ is an identity element then $\hat {f} \hat {g}=\hat{f}$ and choosing $f$ to be one those special functions you get $\hat {g}\equiv 1$. But this cannot be true for any integrable function $g$.

Comment: @epiliam Thanks for editing.